# uipageViewController didnt load view with y=0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am using pagevew controller for the drawer funtionality. Every things working fine but for the first time when view loads then it leave space of status bar and start under the status bar. I need to display view from the y= 0

```
private func setupPageViewController() {
    pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal, options: nil)
    pageViewController.dataSource = self
    pageViewController.delegate = self
    pageViewController.setViewControllers([stackPageVC[stackStartLocation]], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    var pageViewControllerY: CGFloat = 0
    var pageViewControllerH: CGFloat = 0
    if navigationBarShouldNotExist {
        pageViewControllerY = 0
        pageViewControllerH = Constants.ScreenHeight
    } else {
        pageViewControllerY = 0
        pageViewControllerH = Constants.ScreenHeightWithoutStatusBar
    }
    pageViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: pageViewControllerY, width: Constants.ScreenWidth, height: pageViewControllerH)
    
    
    pageViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
    pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            
}
```

I tried to use

```
for v: UIView in pageViewController.view.subviews {
        if (v is UIScrollView) {
            let scroll = v as! UIScrollView
            scroll.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: false)
            print("----")
        }
    }
```

for drawer functionality i am using this library [drawer](https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwipeController)

It is showing like this [image: showing like this]and want to display like this [image: want to display like this]

one thing is that if i touches anywhere on screen then it goes to normal

Comment: just selct the storyboard where you put pageviewcontroller and in right side there is one option UnderTopBar just deselect that option. and you will get solution. or may be you just set constraint with toplayout so set that from toplayout to view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just selct the storyboard where you put pageviewcontroller and in right side there is one option UnderTopBar just deselect that option. and you will get solution. or may be you just set constraint with toplayout so set that from toplayout to view